# Gulp watch multiple directories and set paths relatively

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

For a drupal project, I have multiple themes configured, and during development, themes might be added dynamically.

The themes all have the same structure and reside in the same folder. When I change a sass file in any of the sub theme folders, I want to compile the file to css in the same sub theme's css folder without having to explicitly add every sub theme hard coded in the gulp file.

Can someone help me with setting up the paths ?

```
web/sites/all/themes/contrib/*theme_name*
```

Sass folder:

```
web/sites/all/themes/contrib/*theme_name*/stylesheets
```

CSS folder:

```
web/sites/all/themes/contrib/*theme_name*/css
```

Gulp code

```
 /**
 * @task sass
 * Compile files from scss
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('web/sites/all/themes/contrib/**/stylesheets/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], {cascade: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/style.css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

/**
 * @task watch
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Clear cache when Drupal related files are changed
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['web/sites/all/themes/contrib/**/stylesheets/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('**/*.{php,inc,info}', ['reload']);
});
```

Comment: Nealv - this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859691/gulp-handling-multiple-themes-and-folders